# How to decrease the width of selector in spinner in monodroid?

Tags: android, spinner, selector, xamarin.android

How to decrease the width of selector in spinner in monodroid?[image]

I want the selector (highlighted part) to have less width.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is no way to do this, only to build custom spinner control.